# How to rewrite the website URL in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

is there a way to replace an url with the .htaccess like this:

```
http://website.com/file.php?watch=video
```

to this one:

```
http://website.com/file/watch/video
```

Tried with this,and haven't worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/watch/([\d]+)$ $1.php?watch=$2 [L]
```

My .htaccess file:

```
#remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become 
https://example.com/file
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/watch/([\w-]+)$ $1.php?watch=$2 [L]
```

Comment: It's not working for me, I still get the same URL.
Tried on xampp

Comment: Updated in my main post!

Comment: How do you mean this? 
Put this line: `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/watch/([\w-]+)$ $1.php?watch=$2 [L] `   after  the
RewriteEngine on in the 3rd line?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220101/discussion-between-stereomc-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([\w-]+)\.php\?watch=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/watch/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/watch/([\w-]+)$ $1.php?watch=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Okay,I don't wanna bother you anymore, but this is still not working for me on localhost